# Python dataframe select all rows with list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a dataframe with multiple columns and I want to retrieve all rows where a list of values are found in let say column M for a given value in another column (column g). Also can happen that in column M you don't have any value from the list and want to identify and print rows where that happens.
Sorry I cant provide an example right now and hope it makes sense, I might be able to get a sample of what I want/need later

I tried a for loop with an if statement
methods={ MA, RE, DO]
if  row['M'] in methods  ##some code here

if row['M'] == 'X'  ## some code

and at the end it prints all lines anyways....

Comment: `out = df.loc[df['M'].isin(methods)]`